# Swagger and JsonStringEnumConverter at property level

Tags: serialization, enums, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

We have a .NET 6 application utilising `System.Text.Json` and Swashbuckle v6.5.0.

Is there a way to tell Swagger UI to show enum properties as strings instead of ints? I know there are a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. Declare globally in `Program.cs` like so: `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); });`
2. Decorate the enum declaration itself with this attribute: `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`.

But both of these approaches are too global, one should be able to control this at an individual enum property level by decorating it with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` attribute like so:

```
public record Address
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public AddressType? AddressType { get; set; }

    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string? AddressLine { get; set; }
}
```

I think this is something that Swashbuckle or Swagger needs to fix up on their end. But apart from that, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: how does yaml look like for `public AddressType? AddressType { get; set; }`? because `AddressType `is nullable enum